# Choosing $C_0$ to make second row zero for Garbled Row Reduction (GRR3)

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

In GRR3,we make the first row of the Garbled table to be zero by choosing a special value of $C_1$.

Why don't we make the second row also zero by choosing a special value of $C_0$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the point/permute bits (color bits), the 1st and 2nd ciphertexts might involve the same $C_i$ value.
For example, imagine the point/permute bits are such that the basic garbled truth table is:

$$\begin{aligned}E(C_0) \\ E(C_0) \\ E(C_1) \\ E(C_0) \end{aligned}$$

Once you choose $C_0$ to make the first entry all zeroes, the second entry will be fixed and you cannot make it zero as well.
The row-reduction technique needs to work the same way, regardless of the point/permute bits -- otherwise the gate will leak information about the meaning of the color bits.

**However**, after you choose one of the $C$-values to make the first entry all zeroes, you can always choose the other $C$-value to make the *XOR of the remaining entries* all zero. Here is a screenshot from a [lecture](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Erosulekm/cryptabit/2-gc.pdf) I gave summarizing the technique:

[image]

No matter which of $C_0,C_1$ appears in the first row, the "other" one appears an odd number of times in the other 3 rows, so you can always cause these 3 rows to sum to zero by careful choice of the other $C_i$.
So now you no longer need to send the first entry (it is always zero), and you no longer need to send the last entry (it is always the XOR of the remaining two).
This elegant technique is due to [Gueron, Lindell, Nof, and Pinkas](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/751).

On a personal note, I am interested to know where you got your screenshot, since it is.. let's say "significantly inspired" by [my slides](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Erosulekm/pubs/gc-survey-talk.pdf) from a 2015 survey talk. Like, who is going to all the trouble to completely duplicate my slides verbatim (and make them uglier in the process)?